# Hibernate many to many 3 tables

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a problem with many-mamy relationship in hibernate. 
The idea is: I have an Employee (pracownik) table, a grapfic (grafik) table and a shift (detale zmiany) table. Now I want to have a table where I can check that one employee worked eg. from 01.01-07.01 on a shift 6am-2pm. 
So the table will have columns like idpracownika (employeeid), idgrafiku (graphicid) and idzmiany (shiftid). 
What I have done is:

Pracownik.class

```
@Entity(name = "pracownik")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Proxy(lazy = false)
public class Pracownik

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinTable(name = "grafikpracownika", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idosoby") }, 
inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idgrafiku") })
private List<Grafik> grafiki = new ArrayList<>();

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinTable(name = "grafikpracownika", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idosoby") }, 
inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idzmiany") })
private List<DetaleZmiany> detaleZmiany = new ArrayList<>();
```

Grafik.class

```
@Entity(name = "grafik")
@Proxy(lazy = false)
public class Grafik

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "grafiki", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
private List<Pracownik> pracownik = new ArrayList<>();
```

DataleZmiany

```
@Entity (name = "detalezmiany")
@Proxy(lazy = false)
public class DetaleZmiany {

@ManyToMany (mappedBy = "detaleZmiany",cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
private List <Pracownik> pracownik  = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now I have some record in the pracownik, grafik and detale zmiany table, so now I have only to "combine" it together.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    PracownikService pracowniks = new PracownikService();
    GrafikDao grafikdao = new GrafikDao();
    DetaleZmianyDao dz = new DetaleZmianyDao();

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    Pracownik emp1 = pracowniks.getPracownikById(19);
    Pracownik emp2 = pracowniks.getPracownikById(20);

    Grafik g1 = grafikdao.getGrafikById(1);
    Grafik g2 = grafikdao.getGrafikById(2);

    DetaleZmiany d1 = dz.getDetaleById(1);
    DetaleZmiany d2 = dz.getDetaleById(2);

    emp1.getGrafiki().add(g1);
    emp1.getGrafiki().add(g2);

    emp1.getDetaleZmiany().add(d1);
    emp1.getDetaleZmiany().add(d2);

    emp2.getGrafiki().add(g2);
    emp2.getDetaleZmiany().add(d1);

    pracowniks.updatePracownik(emp1);
    pracowniks.updatePracownik(emp2);

}
```

Trying this code I am getting an exception like `"null value in column "idgrafiku" violates not-null constraint"` 
I have also checked the the sql insert and it looks like:

```
    insert 
into
    grafikpracownika
    (idosoby, idzmiany) 
values
    (?, ?)
```

So the idgrafiku is skipped by that insert. Why? 
Could you help? 
I tried several options but without success....

Answer (score 0):

You want to map 2 relationships in 1 association table (pracownik <-> grafik, pracownik <-> zmiany). This is fine, however it is not so straight-forward to implement using ORM such as Hibernate.

What happens is, that Hibernate has no way (based on your definitions) to know both relationships are in the same association, and thus considers them as 2 **different** associations. Because of this, it tries to insert 2 rows into the association table (grafikpracownika), each of these two having null in one of the columns. This is why you get a null-constraint violation.

What you neeed to do is to add a new entity that will be representing the association. Now, I do not really understand the meaning of "grapfic", so I will just give it a generic name "Assoc". It will obviously have 3 properties: idosoby, idgrafiku, idzmiany. Now link your Pracownik only to Assoc.

To solve the problem of finding the time interval when employee worked, you can simply iterate over all Assocs of Pracownik and filter the ones you are interested in. However if your database will contain many entries, for the sake of efficiency I strongly recommend removing the `FetchType.EAGER` modifiers and use the default lazy loading instead. Then it will make sense to use HQL to leave filtering up to the database.